# Bulk loading into Oracle with all tables in one data file

Tags: oracle

I would like to bulk load a bunch of data into a Oracle database. I have written a program to easily format my data however I want. I see many examples of loading a csv file into Oracle, but they all require a control file for each table, linking it to one file.

It would be simple for me to create a script to generate all of the control files, however I would first like to know if it would be possibly to have all data in one file with table names designated in the data file?

For example:

```
onefile.csv:
------------
details
1, John, john@gmail.com
2, Steve, steve@gmail.com
3, Sally, sally@gmail.com
account
1, John, johntheman, johnh43
2, Steve, password, steve.12
3, Sally, letmein, slllya2
```

*Disclaimer: This is a completely fictional database design and is not at all reflective of how I might store user data in the real world.*

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: I don't believe putting the source data for multiple tables into a single file is possible however as a side note, regarding the loading of data from a non-Oracle database source, you can also use external tables rather than sqlldr, depending on what you're doing with the data it might be useful (you can use them in inserts into other tables, CTAS queries, and the like, one of the biggest advantages being able to limit what rows you load) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could use UTL_FILE to read a CSV.  This would give you complete control over how you process its contents.  But it does mean you would waste a lot of time and effort hand-rolling a meagre and slow implementation of SQL*Loader.  Why would you want to do that?

One file per data source and/or target is the accepted convention for CSV generation.  It is a necessary part of the contract.  If we want to do anything else then we need to use a more suitable protocol such as XML or JSON, somethinhg which can support programmatic interrogation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use SQLLdr? See SQLdr [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005798). See "Distinguishing Different Input Record Formats".

> **Benefits of Using Multiple INTO TABLE Clauses**
>
> **Multiple INTO TABLE clauses enable you to:**
>
> Load data into different tables
>
> Extract multiple logical records from a single input record
>
> Distinguish different input record formats
>
> Distinguish different input row object subtypes

But you would have to specify table name(or it's ID) on every line.
SQLLrd works on line level, I afraid it does not support stanzas.

So you might need to change it into:

```
onefile.csv:
------------    
details,1, John, john@gmail.com
details,2, Steve, steve@gmail.com
details,3, Sally, sally@gmail.com
account,1, John, johntheman, johnh43
account,2, Steve, password, steve.12
account,3, Sally, letmein, slllya2
```

Which looks like a reminisce of old COBOL formats.